Как обрезать только 2 знака после точки

Добрый день, нужна ваша помощь, как обрезать(Не округлить) число после точки
Вот пример моего кода, но он не работает

function button() {
        num1 = display.innerText;
        num2 = disp.innerText;
        alert("Ваше число" + " " + num1 * num2);
        var x = num1 * num2;
        console.log( Math.floor( x * 100 ) / 100 );
    }


Метод toFixed() преобразует число в строку, сохраняя указанное число десятичных знаков. Подробнее

@Rudi оно округляет

@АлексейШиманский Верно. Был подобный вопрос здесь

Вообще, Math.floor( x * 100 ) / 100 у меня работает и дает нужный результат. При каком x у вас выводится результат, не соответствующий ожиданиям?

Ваш код работает, но обратите внимание как именно:


const display = document.querySelector('.display');
const disp = document.querySelector('.disp');

function button() {
  // 1. получаем текст из элемента `display`
  num1 = display.innerText;
  
  // 2. получаем текст из элемента `disp`
  num2 = disp.innerText;
  
  // 3. Показываем окно "Alert", где выполняем умножение `num1` на `num2`
  alert("Ваше число" + " " + num1 * num2);
  
  // 4. создаём переменную x, где умножаем `num1` на `num2`
  var x = num1 * num2;
  
  // 5. "обрезаем" после точки на 2 символа и отображаем результат в консоль.
  console.log( Math.floor( x * 100 ) / 100 );
}

button();
<div class="display">2.35</div>
<div class="disp">4.5</div>



Алексей вам дал дельный совет, почитайте основы данного ЯП.
На 3м этапе выполняете действие с умножением и отображением.
А на 4м этапе отдельно выполняете умножение, а на 5м этапе показываете результат - этот момент вам и нужен. Но вместо этого, вы отображаете его в другом месте - в консоли, которую пользователь даже не видит (пока не откроет её на F12, если он знает о такой возможности).
Чтобы ваш код заработал "как вам хотелось бы", нужно сделать следующий порядок:


const display = document.querySelector('.display');
const disp = document.querySelector('.disp');

function button() {
  // 1. получаем текст из элемента `display`
  num1 = display.innerText;
  
  // 2. получаем текст из элемента `disp`
  num2 = disp.innerText;
  
  // 3. создаём переменную x, где умножаем `num1` на `num2`
  var x = num1 * num2;
  
  // 4. "обрезаем" после точки на 2 символа и отображаем окно "Alert" с результатом
  alert("Ваше число" + " " + Math.floor( x * 100 ) / 100);
}

button();
<div class="display">2.35</div>
<div class="disp">4.5</div>




Ну и от var стоит отказаться :)

Спасибо! теперь понял как оно должно работать



let num = 44.23123.toString();
let result = num.substring(0, num.indexOf('.') + 3);

console.log(result);




Если есть вероятность, что после точки может быть меньше двух чисел, то следует это учесть и проверить

Возможно вставить в let num не цифры, а число, что выходит после выполнения alert(точнее умножения тех двух чисел в нём)

Вставьте. Законом это не запрещено. Тут показан пример как сделать то, что просили

Бы ли бы знания, то без проблем, а так вынужден обратится к людям с более обширными знаниями

У вас есть эти знания. И более того, вы их уже в своём вопросе демонстрируете.

Я примерно понимаю как это должно быть, но написать код не выходит через alert, ранее я выводил просто на  и вместо x просто вписывал id дива, но тут вообще не доганяю

Я не понимаю что вы от меня хотите

Ничего, вы сказали, что у меня достатычно знаний, но я не доганяю как это сделать, уже более полу часа сижу и пробую разные варианты, а так как я подумал, что вы поняли, как это сделать, то скажете мне примерную ошибку

Вопрос был: как обрезать 2 знакак после точки.. Ответ дан..... Если вам не хватает базовых знаний по языку программирования, то вам надо прочитать книжку по основам языка. Элементарные вещи в виде "как в переменную положить результат выражения" написан в любой книжке для начинающих и эту тему мусолить миллионный раз ещё и на текущем ресурсе нет никакого смысла.

Понял, спасибо, я сегодня поищу ещё информации, что бы сделать под свои нужды
